Xero API - 'The discount rate '0.00' is invalid.' error when creating invoice with the line item which has negative amount
I've got BadRequest with an error "A validation exception occurred The discount rate '0.00' is invalid.", when trying to send create Invoice request via API, when invoice has line items with negative amount. At the same time, I can create Invoice with negative line items via UI. Is this possible using API at all? C
Request:
{
    "AmountDue": 1.0,
    "AmountPaid": 0.0,
    "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "080d6f7d-db12-4a35-ae52-de5a4e815b4d"
    },
    "CurrencyCode": "CAD",
    "CurrencyRate": 0.0,
    "Date": "2024-05-02T15:22:44",
    "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "AccountCode": "200",
            "Description": "item2",
            "DiscountAmount": 0.0,
            "DiscountRate": "0.00000",
            "ItemCode": "item2",
            "LineAmount": 10.0,
            "Quantity": 1.0,
            "TaxAmount": 0.0,
            "UnitAmount": 10.0
        },
        {
            "AccountCode": "200",
            "Description": "item3",
            "DiscountAmount": 0.0,
            "DiscountRate": "0.00000",
            "ItemCode": "item3",
            "LineAmount": -9.0,
            "Quantity": 1.0,
            "TaxAmount": 0.0,
            "UnitAmount": -9.0
        }
    ],
    "SentToContact": false,
    "Status": "DRAFT",
    "SubTotal": 1.0,
    "Total": 1.0,
    "TotalDiscount": 0.0,
    "TotalTax": 0.0,
    "Type": "ACCREC"
}

Expect it to work, since it is possible via UI.

Please can you raise a case with Xero Support here and provide details of your app name, app client id and the date and time of the most recent error
